# Getting random numbers in Java

Tags: java, random

I would like to get a random value between 1 to 50 in Java.

How may I do that with the help of `Math.random();`?

How do I bound the values that `Math.random()` returns?

Comment: It would be better to use Random Instead of Math.random. Random is more efficient and less biased.

Comment: [`ThreadLocalRandom#nextInt( int origin , int bound )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt(int,int))

Answer (score 883, accepted):

The first solution is to use the `java.util.Random` class:

```
import java.util.Random;

Random rand = new Random();

// Obtain a number between [0 - 49].
int n = rand.nextInt(50);

// Add 1 to the result to get a number from the required range
// (i.e., [1 - 50]).
n += 1;
```

Another solution is using `Math.random()`:

```
double random = Math.random() * 49 + 1;
```

or

```
int random = (int)(Math.random() * 50 + 1);
```

Comment: So if I take 45 as a minimum and `rand.nextInt(50)` returns 30, I get a value between 45 and 50? Uhm... ok...

Comment: @DanielF 's confusion is understandable because the comment in the answer is misleading. The 50  in `rand.nextInt(50)` will only give the maximum in this situation. `rand.nextInt(50)` will return an integer between 0 (inclusively) and 50 (exclusively) (in other words [0-49]). We add 1 to have [1-50]. So, if you take 45 as a minimum and add it to rand.nextInt(50), you'll have a value between 45 and 94 inclusively.

Comment: @The_Rafi Indeed. `rand.nextInt(1)` will only return 0, not 1 or 0.

Comment: CAUTION!!  util.Random has implemented at Java 8.

Comment: it will give output 1 to 49

Comment: So rand.nextInt(6) + 45 would generate random number 45-50

Comment: @Popeye Yes. rand.nextInt(6) will give you [0-5] and adding 45 to the result makes it [45-50]

Comment: What if I want to generate two numbers, first number I have generated say 34 and now I want to generate one more random numbers excluding number 34. The thing is when I have input list which has very minimum element( note: the list is dynamic)

Answer (score 625):

```
int max = 50;
int min = 1;
```

## 1. Using **Math.random()**

```
double random = Math.random() * 49 + 1;
or
int random = (int )(Math.random() * 50 + 1);
```

This will give you value from 1 to 50 in case of int
or 1.0 (inclusive) to 50.0 (exclusive) in case of double

> Why?
>
> random() method returns a random
>   number between 0.0 and 0.9..., you
>   multiply it by 50, so upper limit
>   becomes 0.0 to 49.999... when you add 1, it becomes 1.0 to 50.999..., now when you truncate to int, you get 1 to 50. (thanks to @rup in comments). [leepoint's](http://www.leepoint.net/algorithms/random/random-api.html) awesome write-up on both the approaches.

## 2. Using Random class in Java.

```
Random rand = new Random(); 
int value = rand.nextInt(50);
```

This will give value from 0 to 49.

For 1 to 50: `rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;`

[Source](http://www.geneseo.edu/~baldwin/reference/random.html) of some Java Random awesomeness.

Comment: "0.0 to 50.0, when you add 1, it becomes 1.0 to 50.0" is surely not correct? There must be 49 or a 51 somewhere there.

Comment: @Blorgbeard the quote's wrong; the result is greater-than-or-equal-to 0 but strictly less than 1 ([documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random() ). So it's 0.0 to 49.999 etc. which becomes 1 to 50.999 etc. when you add 1, which becomes 1 to 50 when you truncate to int.

Comment: it did not work for all ranges
for example .. it gives me 31 when i tried to get a number between 28 and 7

Comment: @Maysara I updated the 2nd example to handle random ranges. The specific example was to use from 1-50.

Comment: if you want numbers  between 8 and 50 the first version you will get values between 8 and 58. You would need a formula like this to get it right  . . . . . .  (int)(Math.random() * (50-8) + 8)