# How to Add Random Colors in For Loop

Tags: android, for-loop

I have a custom PieChart View, right now I'm setting a random color for each pie in a for loop with

```
color = Color.argb(100, r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256)); 
pie.addItem(PieName, PieValue, color);
```

As you can imagine i get strange colors sometimes, or nearly same colors. So now I'm thinking about using certain colors, how can I set some colors like blue, green, red, yellow... then use one of them for every pie in for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are very limited color palettes already in Android (see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html)), but even these lack any kind of collection interface.  You have a couple of options:

1. Create a list of colors that you want to use, and access the list via random offset.  If you are looking for a standard color set, try something [like this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colornames.asp).  Code might look like this:

   ```
       ArrayList<Integer> randColors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       randColors.add(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));

       randColors.add(Color.parseColor("BlanchedAlmond"));
       randColors.add(Color.parseColor("MediumAquaMarine"));
   ```
2. Increment your colors in a predictable way.  I did this code once in Python, but you could easily convert it if it's useful to you:

   ```
       STEPS = 6
       BIG = 0x330000
       MED = 0x003300
       SMA = 0x000033

       count = 1
       num = 0x000000
       for k in range(0, STEPS):
           for j in range(0, STEPS):
               for i in range(0, STEPS):
                    num = ( k * BIG ) + ( j * MED ) + ( i * SMA )
                    print phex(num)
                    count += 1

       def phex(num):
           return "0x%0.6X" % num
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You should create an array of colours you want to use (like red green orange).

Then generate a random number and use it as a key to get a random colour out of the array.

If you don't want duplicates you will have to maintain another list of the keys you have already used.

```
Color[] colors = {new Color(255,0,0),new Color(255,255,255),new Color(0,0,255)};  
int random = create_random_number(); //pesudo code
Color my_color = colors[random];
```

Here is an example of creating a random number (to use inplace of create_random_number): [Getting random numbers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887709/getting-random-numbers-in-java)

Comment: With array of colours do you mean creating a String Array with color codes in it? I look it up and couldn't find an example for it if you didn't mean that.

Comment: No java is an OO lanuage so you should store objects in data structures. An array of colors like above should do the trick.