# Hangman game code:

Tags: java, arrays, methods, syntax

so I'm working on making a simple hangman game on Java. 
The computer should choose a random word from a set of words :

```
public void setWords() {
    words[0] = "notions";
    words[1] = "measure";
    words[2] = "product";
    words[3] = "foliage";
    words[4] = "garbage";
    words[5] = "minutes";
    words[6] = "chowder";
    words[7] = "recital";
    words[8] = "concoct";
    words[9] = "brownie";       
}
```

I'm trying to write the code to generate a random word when the player plays: I have this as a starter:

```
public class Hangman {
private int numwords = 10;
private String[] words = new String[numwords];
private String gameWord;
private String dispWord = "-------";
private char[] dispArr = dispWord.toCharArray();



private static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman!:");

    Random rand= new Random();
    char c = rand.nextChar(setWords);
}
```

Could you please help with the syntax of choosing a random word using the selectGameWord() method? 
Thank you!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5887745/6934695

You can use this one for get random number.

```
    import java.util.Random;

Random rand = new Random();    
int  n = rand.nextInt(words.length);
String word=selectGameWord(n)
```

and selectGameWord(int x);

```
 sentence=words[x];
   return sentence;
```

Edit:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Hangman{
    String words[]={"notions","measure","product","foliage"};



    public String selectGameWord(int x)
    {
        String sentence= words[x]; 
        return sentence; 
    }
    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman!:"); 
        Random rand=new Random(); 
        Hangman myhangman= new Hangman();
        int n= rand.nextInt(myhangman.words.length);        
        String word= myhangman.selectGameWord(n); 
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

Comment: but then I should change the static part to just public void main(String[] args){ right?

Comment: If you have just one class, you don't have to.

Comment: because when I had this code it gave me several errors saying that I "cannot make a static reference to non-static field-words"

Comment: I have a public class hangman{
and public static void main(String[] args){ inside the first class and this is where I had the random code written

Comment: Create a object. Then call the selectGameWord method.

Comment: Let's say your class name is Sapo.

Sapo sapo = new Sapo();
String word = sapo.selectGameWord(n);

Comment: it's still gonna be under the main right? 
public static void main(String[] args){
  System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman!:");
  //pick a random word from the array
  Random rand=new Random();
  int n= rand.nextInt(words.length);
  String word=selectGameWord(n);
  selectGameWord(int x);
  sentence= words[x];
  return sentence;
                Hangman myhangman= new Hangman();
                String word= myhangman.selectGameWord(n);

Comment: I edited my answer, check it out.

Comment: I got that part down! Thank you!

Comment: Done! The tick is now green! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your main you could have the game word selected like this.

`String gameWord = words[rand.nextInt(words.length)];`

The bound of your random number will be from 0 <= x <= 9 if you do `.nextInt(10)'. Because your word array has only ten set choices.

Comment: would I have that after my two line of code? or just instead of my : 
char C= rand.nextChar(setWords);

Comment: You would want that instead of your line with the char C variable.

Comment: but then should it be static?

Comment: All your global class variables need to be static. Example `private static String[] words = new String[numwords];`

Comment: but I need to use selectGameWord() 
How would I add that?

Comment: Make a static method called selectGameWord that returns a string. And then call those lines in that method.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to get a random word from your array? You have to use `Random#nextInt()` to get a random index from your array.

```
Random random = new Random();
int index = random.nextInt(words.length);
String randomWord = words[index];
```

Comment: what does the index refer to?

Comment: @Emily It stores a random Integer between 0 and the Array length - 1. It is a random number.

Comment: I see. But I have to use selectGameWord() in my code

Comment: But then how can I use selectGameWord() in my code?