# random number generator starting with 0 java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a random number generator starting with the number 0 and going to 3. Right now I have this:

```
Random dealerNum = new Random();
int dealer = dealerNum.nextInt(3);
```

Comment: But, whats the question? Is there any error?

Comment: Already answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887709/getting-random-numbers-in-java

Comment: Your code does exactly what you want, i.e. generates a random number 0-3 (inclusive). What problem do you perceive you have?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1))` for generate random number.

A random integer value in the range [Min, Max]
**Min = 0 and Max = 3**

`0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((3 - 0) + 1))` => `(int)(Math.random() * 4)`

`int dealer = (int) (Math.random() * 4);` This will generate random int between 0 and 3 in java.

Answer (score -1):

```
int dealer = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
```

This will give you a random int between 0 and 3. But your code also should work too.

Comment: why did you downvote?

Comment: Down-voted because: 1) No explanation. 2) Not an improvement over code already in question. --- Hence: *Not useful.*

Comment: added an explanation

Comment: Also down-voted because it's not an answer to the question. How could it be? We have no idea what the question actually is. Writing an answer that gives same result is certainly not it.

Comment: I think that the author implies that he wants to know if his/her code work and what an alternative could be.