# How to fill array with random numbers limited to 0-20

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am having trouble placing the random generator in the array, how can I get #20 random numbers from 0-9 in the array? Then you count the occurrences of those numbers.

import java.util.Random;

public class CountDigits {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {



    Random digit = new Random(); 

    int Random[] = new int [20];

    int Digits[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; 

    int Count [] = new int [10]; 


    for ( int i = 0; i < Digits.length; i++) {


        for( int j = 0; j < Random.length; j++) {

            if ( Digits [i] == Random [j] ) 
                Count[i]++; 
        }

    }


    for ( int i = 0; i < Count.length; i++) {

        if ( Count[i] == 1) 
            System.out.printf(" %d  occurs  1 time " , Digits[i] ); 

        else
            System.out.printf("%d occurs %d times" , Digits[i], Count[i]); 

    }
```

result so far::
0 occurs 20 times1 occurs 0 times2 occurs 0 times3 occurs 0 times4 occurs 0 times5 occurs 0 times6 occurs 0 times7 occurs 0 times8 occurs 0 times9 occurs 0 times

Comment: "How to fill array with random numbers limited to 0-20" | "how can I get #20 random numbers from 0-9 in the array" - Which is it?

Comment: *"I am having trouble placing the random generator in the array"* Why would you want to? You only need one random generator, so why put *it* in an array? You'd want to put the generated random *numbers* in the array, so to begin with, change `int Random[] = new int [20];` to `int[] numbers = new int[20];`

Comment: Parts duplicate of [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/363681/5221149)

Comment: In addition to the various other comments, you need to pay attention to Java style conventions.  1) The identifier for a variable should *never* start with an uppercase letter.  2) The name for an identifier should reflect what the variable is *used for*.  So for example, calling your random number generator `digit` is wrong.  It is not a digit.  It is a random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign random numbers to the array elements.[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5887745/9483495) to see how random numbers are generated.

You need to call Random object's nextInt(an integer) method. If you give 25 to it, it will return a random integer between 0-24 inclusive.

**Example Usage:**

```java
Random rand = new Random();
int random_int = rand.nextInt(50); // --------> Random integer 0-49
```

**And the full code**:

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Random digit = new Random();

        int Random[] = new int[20];

        for (int x=0;x<20;x++) {
            Random[x] = digit.nextInt(10);
        }

        int Digits[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

        int Count[] = new int[10];


        for (int i = 0; i < Digits.length; i++) {


            for (int j = 0; j < Random.length; j++) {

                if (Digits[i] == Random[j])
                    Count[i]++;
            }

        }


        for (int i = 0; i < Count.length; i++) {

            if (Count[i] == 1)
                System.out.printf(" %d  occurs  1 time ", Digits[i]);

            else
                System.out.printf("%d occurs %d times", Digits[i], Count[i]);

        }
    }
}
```

Outputs :

```
0 occurs 2 times1 occurs 2 times 2  occurs  1 time 3 occurs 3 times4 occurs 6 times 5  occurs  1 time 6 occurs 2 times7 occurs 0 times 8  occurs  1 time 9 occurs 2 times
```

You can print the random numbers like this

```
 for (int x=0;x<20;x++) {
        System.out.println(Random[x]);
    }
```

Comment: How can I print those 20 numbers before determining the count ?

Comment: I added to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually get a Random number, and get within the range. The [Java Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) will provide the necessary capability, and includes a `.nextInt(int bound)` that returns between 0 and `bound`:

> **public int nextInt(int bound)**
>
> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

So something like:

```
Random rnd = new Random();

int num = rnd.nextInt(10);  // returns between 0 and 9
```

Given that, you have two other questions:
 - Generating 20 numbers
 - Counting

Knowing that the number of possible entries is between 0 and 9, it is easy to use an array to hold the counts.

```
int[] counts = new int[10];  // holds between 0 and 9
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
  int num = rnd.nextInt(10);
  counts[num]++;
}
```

The output of the `counts` array will give the count of the number of times a given number between 0 and 9 was randomly generated.

See an [example here](https://ideone.com/Jz4JdK)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Create an array of int with length 20, then use a simple for loop where you are gonna generate a random number and them put it inside the array

```java
int[] random = new int[20];

for(int i=0;i<20;i++){

    int r = Math.floor(Math.random()*9+1);
    random[i]=r;
}
```

Comment: Try explaining your code, it will help people :)