# How to print out a random character of a string?

Tags: java, string, random, char, character

I have an assignment due for my java course and I cant figure out how to print out a random character from a string the user has input, can anyone lend a hand?

Currently I have some code that looks like this

```java
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);          

            String input = keyboard.next();

            Random random = new Random();
            char index = random.charAt(input.length());

            System.out.println("Here is a random Character ");
            System.out.println(index);
```

Comment: You can generate a random number `r` between `0` and `string.length()` , and then return `str.charAt(r)`.  (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887709/getting-random-numbers-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);          

    String input = keyboard.next();

    Random random = new Random();
    char index = input.charAt(random.nextInt(input.length()));

    System.out.println("Here is a random Character ");
    System.out.println(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify this line:

```
char index = random.charAt(input.length());
```

to

```
char index = input.charAt(random.nextInt(input.length()));
```

`Random` does not have a `charAt` method, rather `String` does.  So you need to use `charAt` of the `String` and pass it an integer.

This integer should be the random number generated based of the length of the `String`. This can be created using `random.nextInt(input.length())` which creates a random number from `0` to the `length - 1`.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhh ok, thanks for explaining. I was able to get the program to print a random int but couldn't figure out why charAt wasn't working. Thanks a ton =D

Comment: @Bronson3123 No problem, please accept one of the answers given here that best answered your question using the checkmark so the question gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can get random character from string like below:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);          

String input = keyboard.next();

Random rand = new Random();
int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(input.length());

System.out.println("Here is a random Character ");
System.out.println(input.charAt(randomIndex));
```

I hope it helps!