# java word game logic

Tags: java, if-statement, logic

Hi I have to create a game for two players where one player guesses the word starting on random char , min 3 letters long and should be in word base, the second player word should meet last 2 conditions plus should start on two last letters of the word provided by first player. Both players start with 3 lives. Example:
random word:e
firstPlayer:echo
secondPlayer:hollow

Do you think that using multiple nested if statements will be fine? How to add random char at first attempt?

```
if(longer than 3){
   if(in word base){
        if(starting with 2 letters from previous last letters){
           currentPlayerPoints+=1;
           message="Thats right you got a point";
        }else{
           currentPlayerLives-=0;
           message="you didnt match the word";
        }
    }else{
        message="your word is not in database";
        currentPlayerLives-=0;
    }
}else{
    message="your word should be longer at least 3 letters long";
    currentPlayerLives-=0;
}
```

Comment: It's probably fine... Although I don't know how I feel about the subtracting zero part. For randomness, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887709/getting-random-numbers-in-java)

Comment: my code is a mess at this moment and above i added pseudo code but for random char i have somethibg like that:
`
private char[] alphabet={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','o','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
private char randomChar;
randomChar=alphabet[(int)Math.floor(Math.random()*26)];
`

Comment: Use [ascii values](http://www.asciitable.com/).
Basically, each char has a numerical value (a=97, b=98, etc.). You can use this to your advantage and just get a random number from 97 to 122 inclusive, then cast to char.

Comment: Great idea, Thank you!